# React - keep all state management in Context Provider while using an async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find a more elegant way to create a provider/consumer where an async call is made from the provider, but the consumer doesn't have to manage state.

I have a context provider where I'm fetching to see if feature flags are enabled:

```js
  const [featureFlags, setFeatureFlag] = useState({});

  async function checkFeatureFlag(someKey) {
    if (typeof featureFlags[someKey] === 'boolean') {
      return featureFlags[someKey]
    } else {
      // returns a promise
      const result = await evaluateFeatureFlag(someKey);
      
      setFeatureFlag({[someKey]: result})

      return result;
    }
  }

  return (
    <FeaturesContext.Provider value={{ checkFeatureFlag }}>
      {children}
    </FeaturesContext.Provider>
  );
```

In my consumer I'm trying to pass a feature flag key and determine if the flag is enabled, but only after the promise is resolved. I want all of the state to be handled from the Context Provider, so I don't want to have to do a `useEffect` or `useState` at all in my consumer.

```js
  const { checkFeatureFlag } = useFeaturesContext();

  const isEnabled = checkFeatureFlag('My_cool_feature');

  return isEnabled ? <div>Show feature</div> : <div>feature is hidden</div>
```

This will not work unless I add an `await` in front of `checkFeatureFlag`, which won't work unless I add an `async` in front of the component, which is not support in React (I don't think).

I can add a `useEffect` here so that I can make the async call, but then I have to add a `useState` to the component as well. Again, I'd like all of the state to be handled from the context, because I'm trying to create a clean API that's easy for other engineers to use.

To summarize, I'd like a provider that makes an async call where the consumer doesn't have to care about state management at all.

Comment: I don't get it why you can't add both `useState` and `useEffect` in the provider

Comment: The child component/consumer needs to be responsible for kicking off the feature flag check, not the provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A setup like this could work

```
const FreaturesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [featureFlags, setFeatureFlag] = useState({});

  async function checkFeatureFlag(someKey) {
    if (
      typeof featureFlags[someKey] === "boolean" ||
      featureFlags[someKey] === null
    ) {
      return;
    } else {
      // set null so it won't make two requests
      setFeatureFlag({ [someKey]: null });
      // returns a promise
      const result = await evaluateFeatureFlag(someKey);
      setFeatureFlag({ [someKey]: result });
    }
  }

  // you can skip this and just pass `featureFlags` in value
  const isEnabled = (someKey) => {
    return featureFlags[someKey] || false;
  };

  return (
    <FeaturesContext.Provider value={{ isEnabled, checkFeatureFlag }}>
      {children}
    </FeaturesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
const { isEnabled, checkFeatureFlag } = useFeaturesContext();

// just check for flag
// the component should rerender automatically
// when the response come back
checkFeatureFlag("My_cool_feature");

return isEnabled("My_cool_feature") ? (
  <div>Show feature</div>
) : (
  <div>feature is hidden</div>
);
```

### Version with one function

```
const FreaturesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [featureFlags, setFeatureFlag] = useState({});

  function checkFeatureFlag(someKey) {
    if (
      typeof featureFlags[someKey] === "boolean" ||
      featureFlags[someKey] === null
    ) {
      return featureFlags[someKey] || false;
    } else {
      // set null so it won't make two requests
      setFeatureFlag({ [someKey]: null });

      evaluateFeatureFlag(someKey).then((result) => {
        setFeatureFlag({ [someKey]: result });
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  return (
    <FeaturesContext.Provider value={{ heckFeatureFlag }}>
      {children}
    </FeaturesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const { isEnabled, checkFeatureFlag } = useFeaturesContext();

const isEnabled = checkFeatureFlag("My_cool_feature");

return isEnabled ? <div>Show feature</div> : <div>feature is hidden</div>;
```

Comment: would it be possible to have the return value of `checkFeatureFlag` return true/false instead of having to call 2 separate functions with the same argument?